# Issues with Flashlight Handle position with player rotation

Tags: unity, rotation, lighting, unityscript, character-development

I want the flashlight to look same while looking up and down as when looking straight.

Normal Position for Hand and flashlight: [image]

Looking up and down, position is completely off:
[image]
[image]

More images for character/camera prefab rotation:
[image]
[image]

Basically the position of the Hand held flashlight changes when I look up or down, as well as the arm stretches. How do I fix this?

Code for character rotation:

```
private void CharacterRotation()
{
    float posX = Input.GetAxis(mouseX) * ((StructsInitializers.Sensitivity * 5) + StructsInitializers.Sensitivity*50) * Time.deltaTime;
    float posY = Input.GetAxis(mouseY) * ((StructsInitializers.Sensitivity * 5) + StructsInitializers.Sensitivity*50) * Time.deltaTime;
    yAxisClamp += posY;

    if(yAxisClamp > 90.0f)
    {
        yAxisClamp = 90.0f;
        posY = 0.0f;
        ClampYAxisRotation(270.0f);
    }
    else if(yAxisClamp < -90)
    {
        yAxisClamp = -90.0f;
        posY = 0.0f;
        ClampYAxisRotation(90.0f);
    }
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.left * posY);
    PlayerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * posX);
}

private void ClampYAxisRotation(float value)
{
    Vector3 eulerRotation = transform.eulerAngles;
    eulerRotation.x = value;
    transform.eulerAngles = eulerRotation;
}
```

PS: I am new to game developing. I have lack of experience.

Comment: Do you have a non-uniform scale on the parent object that contains your camera and arm?

Comment: I'm not sure, how do I find that out? PS: I'm new at game developing so I lack experience.

Comment: Click on it and look at the scale values of the Transform component in the inspector. You're looking for one value (probably y) that's different from the others.

Comment: I test played, and I was rotating to see. No values change in HandHeld Flashlight prefab. So I think that's the issue.

Comment: What you describe is not the way to diagnose this particular problem. A non-uniform scale inherited from a parent will not be shown in the inspector when you select the child object.